# QuoteLineItem related list, Add Line Item => Select Button Override with Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, quotelineitem

I am wanting to override the `Select` button on the Product Selection page for a quote, where you add `QuoteLineItem`'s with a Visualforce page. Which you get to by clicking the `Add Line Item` button on the Quote Line Items related list on a `Quote` detail view.

[image: Add line item button]

**And the button I would like to override with a VF page:**

[image]

I have poked around for a bit trying to find this button somewhere in setup, but haven't seen it.

I know I can override the `Add Line Item` button, but I don't want to recreate the first page which works for our business flow, just so I can have that button send to another VF page.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to `OpportunityLineItem`, if you want to change the <kbd>Select</kbd> button, you need to override the entire <kbd>Add Line Item</kbd> button. It is not bound to any action on its own.

First create a `Visualforce Page` on the `Quote` object.

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote">
    <!--content-->
</apex:page>
```

Now, if you go to `Customize` > `Quotes` > `Quote Line Items` > `Buttons and Links`. Select `Add Line Item`. Edit it to reference the `Visualforce Page` created above.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't what I was asking. I want to override the `Select` button on the following page without overriding the `Add Line Item` button. Which I don't think is possibly without overriding the first button, but I figured I would ask before I wrote two VF pages instead of one.

Comment: @JesseMilburn You have to override the whole `Add Line Item` action if you want to modify that `Select`.